# Sending Emails With SQL Server 2005: do I use a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure when it is appropriate to use a cursor.

I need to send out emails after a certain stored procedure is ran that updates some tables.  So if

```
table1.field1 = "value" and 
   (select count(*) 
      from table1 join table2 
        on table2.table1_id = table1.id) > 20
```

then an email needs to be sent out for everything in table1 that meets those conditions.  And in the email I need to include table1.field2 and table2.field3 and so on...

The only way I can think to do this is get my dataset of rows in table1 that meet these conditions and then use a cursor to go through it.  I've never worked with sending emails from SQL Server before and I don't know my options... I have never used a cursor before (although I do understand how) because I learned to shy away from them.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
With the while loop:  So... I probably want to shove all the info i need into a temp table (select * from table1 where (conditions)) and then start a while loop that goes through each row of the resulting data set in my temp table.  (WHILE i = 1 to (select count(*) from #temp) / assemble e-mail send e-mail / next)... then what is the best way to reference/point to which row of #temp I should be using for each loop iteration?  I could just give #temp an identity(1,1) or use row_number()... right?  I guess?  It seems like I'm just trying to program my own cursor by doing this, though?  And let's say we set @subject = (select 'Site ' & field2 & ' has a value of ' & field1 from #temp where temp_id_or_row_number = @i) and then increment @i for each loop...?

Comment: Just one email with a "report" in it that shows the results of the SQL that meets the conditions? Or one email per line??

Comment: one email per line/row.... not one report email.

Comment: just added a more detailed example to my attempt at the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used something similar to [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/2010/06/15/Building-HTML-Emails-With-SQL-Server-and-XML/) 
I used to build up straight html and then use that in an html formatted mail using `sp_send_dbmail`.
These stored procedures can get messy

I never used cursors - had several stored procs which had WHILE loops sending out multiple emails

```
WHILE (condition)
   begin
   end
```

Here's a full example; hope it helps:

```
/*
drop table #the_table
drop table #Emails
*/
create table #the_table 
( [Email] varchar(50),
  [Date] datetime,
  [Amount] decimal(12, 2))

insert into #the_table
values
( 'example@googlemail.co.uk', '2012-1-1', 10),
( 'example@googlemail.co.uk', '2012-1-3', 10),
( 'foo@bar.co.uk', '2012-1-3', 20),
( 'foo@bar.co.uk', '2012-1-5', 10)


  --get a list of email addresses
SELECT   
    Email
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Email]) AS [Counter] 
INTO    #Emails
FROM    #the_table
GROUP BY Email


DECLARE @html VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @Recipient VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @row INT = 1

WHILE @row <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Emails)
BEGIN
    SET @Recipient= (SELECT [Email] FROM #Emails WHERE [Counter] = @row)


      --start building the html string
    SELECT @html = '<html><p>Hello World.</p>'
    SELECT @html = @html + '<p><table border="1"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th></tr>' 

    SELECT
        @html = 
            @html + 
            ('<tr><td>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), [Date])                           
            + '</td><td>$' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY,Amount),1), LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY,Amount),1))-3) + '</td></tr>')
    FROM    #the_table
    WHERE   [Email] = @Recipient
    SELECT @html = @html + '</table></p>'   

      --finish building the html string 
    SELECT @html = @html + '<p></p></html>'


    DECLARE @mySubject VARCHAR(100)
    SET @mySubject = 'TESTING 1-2-3'

    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = @Recipient  
        , @subject = @mySubject
        , @body_format = 'html'
        , @body = @html 


    SET @Row = @Row +1

END
```

Comment: While loop = cursor with slightly different syntax.

Comment: Yes, I was planning on using sp_send_dbmail.  I don't know/understand how a loop is what I need in this situation.  For every row that meets my conditions I need to send an email to table1.NotificationEmailAddress that includes some info from table1 and some calculated info.  A loop would just get me one big email... right?  I need many individual emails....

Comment: `WHILE i = 1 to 20 / assemble e-mail send e-mail / next` - how is that one big e-mail?

Comment: @AaronBertrand agreed that While loop = cursor; I've seen cursors but never used them. WHILE loops seem pretty straighforward

Comment: Not always. Give this post a good read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/26/the-fallacy-that-a-while-loop-isn-t-a-cursor.aspx

Comment: @gloomy.penguin exactly as aaron says - if you add a row_number into the table with the email info in it and then inside the while loop you query that table using WHERE ROW_NUMBER = i to increment through the rows

Comment: @AaronBertrand ...you really reeled me into that one! ...I'll have a skeet tomorrow